# Weird URI string displayed on mounting iPod

Tags: linux, uri, ipod

I have written a small program to detect whenever a device is mounted on a desktop running Linux. I have used `GIO` for this. I am extracting the URI of the mounted resource and displaying it to the user. When I put in a CD I get a URI string which looks like `file:///media/cdrom0/` which I can understand. But when I mount an iPod the URI I see is something like `gphoto2://[usb:002,028]`. What does this mean? I have observed that the second number (028) keeps increasing every time I take the device out and plug it back in. Can some one interpret this URI for me?

Update: As shodanex answered, the two numbers are the bus number and device number respectively. `gphoto2://` indicates the protocol (PTP/MTP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gphoto2://[usb:002,028]

I guess 002 is the bus number, and 28 is the adress of the device on that bus.
It maps to the second and fourth field of the lsusb util output. Here is an example
on my system :

```
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 05e3:0715 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 microSD Reader
```

I guess it would translate to :

```
usb:001,015
```

Comment: And what would `gphoto2://` part of it mean then?

Comment: Also, why does the second number keep increasing even if I unmount the device and then insert it again? Shouldn't it reuse the previous address?

Comment: It increments because thats how the usb stack in kernel works.

Answer (score 0):

I have these kinds of URL's in Nautilus too, but the other response doesn't explain how that relates to a mount location on disk.  I can navigate through the files on an SD card via the Nautilus file browser, but I don't see any of these files in /mnt/ or /media/ or anywhere else I would typically look for automatically mounted file systems.

Eventually I tried right-clicking the folder, selecting "Open with other application," choosing a text editor, and then I could see that the folder was actually mounted at:
'~/.gvfs/gphoto2 mount on usb%3A001,010'

I wish Nautilus and other tools in ubuntu would provide some more obvious way to find these files... this seems pretty un-intuitive.